# Registrar que se ha cambiado con Trigger

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Estoy haciendo un historial de actualización de los registros en mi base de datos mysql

Tengo dos tablas en phpmyadmin iguales, una que es en la que registro datos y la otra recien creada llamada updateLogs donde actua el disparador de los cambios efectuados en la primera

Necesito que al cambiar un dato en la primera tabla, se registre ese cambio en la segunda, y los demas campos queden vacios como se muestra en el siguiente codigo

```
INSERT INTO avisosLogs VALUES (null, NEW.id, NOW(), '', '', "Se ha cambiado este campo", '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', "Actualizado" )
```

Mi código php para insertar un registro:

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 include 'functions.php';
 verificar_sesion();
 ?>
<?php
$servername = "Localhost";
$username = "**********";
$password = "*********";
$dbname = "***********";
try{

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$numero = $_POST['numero'];
$fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
//etc etc etc



$sql = "INSERT INTO avisos (numero,fecha,cliente,direccion,telefono,averia,estado,parametro,observaciones,tecnico,usuarioLog,lat,lng,prioridad,creador)
VALUES ('$numero','$fecha','$cliente','$direccion','$telefono','$averia','$estado','$parametro','$observaciones','$tecnico','$creador','$lat','$lon','$prioridad','$creador')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
   window.location='redireccionar.php';
   </script>";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo 'Excepción capturada: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Con sólo esto, es difícil saber lo que haces. Supongo que al cambiar algo en la primera query sabes que necesitas cambiar, por lo que necesitarías pasar esos datos a la segunda query.

Comment: Lo que necesito es registrar en la segunda sólo los datos que se hayan modificado

Comment: Bien, y podrías mostrar el código de cómo insertas los cambios en la primera para poder ayudarte con esto?

Comment: Ya he agregado el código para insertar registro en la primera tabla